# Looking for a word to mean not boasting

Tags: word-usage

> I started out lying only when my about-to-be-whipped ass needed saving, but then quickly developed thanks to my, not boasting, superior understanding and thinking skills

The above lines are from a private page. Is there any meaningful word replacement for "not boasting"?

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus?  I note the irony in boasting of not boasting.

Comment: The sentence structure is confusing.  As written it sounds like the main topic is your skill at lying, which you have since developed.  If instead you want to say you now employ other skills than clever falsehoods, then you should reconstruct the sentence to make that more clear.

Comment: @Andrew "Not boasting" refers to the writer's superior understanding and thinking skills

Comment: @JamesK I did search for sometime. Did not find what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to say this. *Bragging* is another word. If I were going to say this I would put it this way:

> thanks to my — and I'm not boasting here — superior understanding and thinking skills.

Here, you can substitute *bragging* for *boasting*.

Of course, everyone knows that the writer *is* boasting, so this is probably intended to be humorous. Another way to say it:

> thanks to my superior understanding and thinking skills (hey, if it's fact it ain't bragging).

Even though it's incorrect, *ain't* is used instead of *isn't* in this phrase (which is also intended to be humorous) to suggest the sort of uneducated wisdom that comes from common sense.

Comment: I like the second one :) Is there a word to refer to such constructs?

Comment: @AnoopMysore There are several words to refer to well-known sayings. *Saw* is perhaps a good one. [Here's](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/saw) the thesaurus entry for *saw*, where you can explore other similar words.

Comment: I meant to ask how to refer to parts of sentences like "... - and I'm not boasting here - ..."

Comment: Oh, sorry. That's called a *parenthetical statement* or just a *parenthetical.* We usually use parentheses to set them off, but dashes give a bigger emphasis. For further explanation of parentheticals, see [here](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/dashes-parentheses-and-commas?page=2).